# Is the gravitational tidal force equivalent to expanding space?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, spacetime, space-expansion, tidal-effect

If you fall towards a black hole, the particles in front and the back of you, in the direction of the center, are accelerating away from you. So, seen from a freely frame, can we say that space is expanding, or that there is a repulsive gravity between the both masses (though not caused by the masses themselves)?

Answer (score 3):

You are neglecting the behavior of particles to the side of you, which are drawn closer. If you start with a spherical ball of coffee grounds then as it falls the ball will be stretched vertically and compressed horizontally into an ellipsoid, but the volume of the ball will remain the same. So it is an example of curvature, but not expansion.

Comment: But then there is expansion as well as contraction.

Comment: In technical terms, this can be thought of in terms of the expansion, shear, and twist of nearby geodesics, which (roughly speaking) tell you how a small sphere of test particles will expand, shear, or twist respectively.  There's a good discussion of this concept in Appendix F of Carroll's *Spacetime and Geometry*.

Comment: @Felicia as Michael Seifert said what you are describing can be decomposed into expansion, shear, and torsion. The expansion scalar is 0 and the shear tensor is non-zero. So, no, there is not expansion as well as contraction, there is shear. These are tensor quantities so they are coordinate independent geometric quantities

Comment: So it doesn't matter if we look from the freely infalling frame?

Comment: @Felicia no, it doesn't matter. That is precisely why we use tensors

Comment: But could the same than be happening for particles in our universe? I mean, can't they, if confined to 3 spatial dimensions, move on a hyperbolic spatially 4D space? So that all particles are driven away from each other if they move in the extra fourth dimension,,?

Comment: So all little cubes inside the coffee ball stay the same. But doesn't it look as if the measures of the cubes change?